# IIS self-signed > 1 year

Tags: iis

In IIS, we can create a self-signed certificate. The expiration of the certificate defaults to one year. Does anyone know whether this can be changed for example via the "Configuration Editor"?

Answer (score 2):

IIS doesn't do anything special when generating a self-signed certificate so you can use and tool for that.

For instance, you can use Powershell. This one-liner will create a self-signed certificate for the DNS name `test` valid for 5 years, with no password and place it into the local machine certificate store (it requires elevation).

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "test" -notAfter $([datetime]::now.AddYears(5)) -CertStoreLocation cert:\Localmachin\My
```